# Alter multiple columns in a single statement

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064, alter-table

I am using a query to alter the charset of a column

```
ALTER TABLE `media_value_report` 
    CHANGE `index_page_body` `index_page_body` TEXT CHARACTER  
    SET utf8 NULL DEFAULT NULL
```

i want to do this for other columns  main_title, landing_page_body as well. But am getting a #1064 error while executing. Can i alter-change multiple columns in  a single query?

I tried but i found in goog search that is not possible to alter in a single query.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

The [documentation suggests](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html) you can chain alter_specifications with a comma:

```
ALTER TABLE `media_value_report` 
    CHANGE col1_old col1_new varchar(10),
    CHANGE col1_old col1_new varchar(10),
    ...
```

Comment: Does this also work with modify?

Comment: @Qsiris the spec suggests it should

Comment: @Qsiris confirmed modify does work like this