# Modifying multiple columns to require value

Tags: mysql

I have created the table and now I need to set 3 columns to require value without inserting again? 
I tryed typing:

```
ALTER TABLE _tablename_   
MODIFY COLUMN _columnname_ , _anotherone_ , .... NOT NULL;
```

but it doesn't work that way.
It works perfectly fine if I do it for single column.

Comment: [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3773498/939697) It is not possible to combine them into one line for the `MODIFY COLUMN` statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you modify a column you have to specify all the attributes. There's no shortcut for just adding `NOT NULL` or doing the same change to multiple columns:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename
MODIFY column1 INT NOT NULL, 
MODIFY column2 VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL, 
MODIFY column3 VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT 'Not set' NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Actually I tried it like that but I think i need to put _modify column_ text 3 times in my case if I want it to work... Correct me if I'm wrong